# Clear combobox datasource items

Tags: .net, winforms, compact-framework

Combobox datasource has been assigned with

```
cmbCombobox.DataSource = myCollection
```

where myCollection has type MyCollection: List

How can I clear items in combobox?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you data bind a control, it will synchronize with that collection. In order to clear the items in your ComboBox set it's DataSource to null.

```
cmbComboBox.DataSource = null;
```

If your combobox is **not** databound (no DataSource) then you can do

```
cmbComboBox.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: Note that setting `DataSource` to `null` seems to also set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` to their default values (I'm guessing null), so if you customized those then presumably you will have to reconfigure that.

Thanks MicroFailSoft for poor documentation and unpredictable behavior! `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 4):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327895

```
Me.ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
```

This works for me.  VB incorrectly advises the use of DBNull (which crashes).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it worked for me:

If your combobox has a DataSource, then simply assigning to a null data source should be enough. However, many times you have to clear the bindings manually:

> comboBoxAssignee.DataSource = null;
>
> comboBoxAssignee.DataBindings.Clear();

If there is no DataSource, then you just clear the items:

> comboBoxAssignee.Items.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

in asp.net you can do like this:

```
cbMyComboBox.Items.Clear();
```

Maybe it works and for winforms) Not sure

Comment: Items.Clear() does not works. In WinForms cmbCombobox.DataSource = myEmptyCollection

Comment: hellboy, your solution doesn't clear the items, just sets it to another source

Comment: try `cbMyComboBox.DataSource = null;` followed by `cbMyComboBox.Items.Clear();`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and .net v4.5 and am creating winforms in VB. The following do not work:

```
me.combobox.Datasource = null
me.combobox.Items.clear()
```

Using Null isn't even an option for the datasource and I get the following error when I tried items.clear(); "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set."

The following does work and I have used it in a number of upgrades to applications.

```
Me.cmboFromLoc.DataSource = Nothing
```

Comment: `me.combobox.Datasource = null` is in C# .NET, which also complies with the user's question. Anyone who programs in either VB .NET or C# .NET should be able to read/translate answers in the other language. Also, [your answer is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20006005/2415524) and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

setting cbMyComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1 works best!