# Clear ComboBox if RadioButton is deactivated

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, radio-button

I have five `RadioButton` and five `ComboBox` controls. 
Each `RadioButton` is connected to a `ComboBox`.

When I activate one `RadioButton`, the corresponding `ComboBox`, it gets enabled.
Now when I choose another `RadioButton`, the information in the previously selected `ComboBox` should clear but does not!

I have tried with `ComboBox.Clear()` as well as `ComboBox.Reset()`, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code for one of the `ComboBox` and `RadioButton`

```
if (radioButtondinner.Checked == true)
        {
            comboBoxdinner.DataSource = DList.Dwork();
            comboBoxdinner.DisplayMember = "dinner";
        }
```

Comment: Code always helps.

Comment: can you please post your code

Comment: And what happens if `Checked == false`?

Comment: Were is the code for clearing the comboboxes?

Comment: I tried  if (radioButtondinner.Checked == false) and then comboxdinner.clear(); or reset but nothing happens ;/ I'm very new at this so sorry if I don't write correctly

Comment: @mo.wl please show the code as you have tried to clear them, it might be that there is a typo or something in there which prevents it from working. But it is a bit of guess work if we don't see the exact code as you have tried. Also the complete method in which you check this will be nice. Do you do this check on the event radiobutton change, or something else?

Comment: you can use one `Combobox` and only to change data sources when you check other `RadioButton` that should work sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear combobox datasource items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376577/clear-combobox-datasource-items)

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comment: you can use one `Combobox` and only to change data sources when you check other `RadioButton` that should work sure
But If you want to have more `Combobox` then just type in `else` statements

```
comboBox.DataSource = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

// create a check change event and use this.

```
private void radioButtondinner_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!radioButtondinner.Checked)
            {
                // if you want to clear only the text or selected item text
                comboBoxdinner.Text = String.Empty;
                // if you want to clear the entire data source
                comboBoxdinner.DataSource = null;
            }

        }
```